# Azure virtual machine scale set with NIC error

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I have Configured Azure virtual machine scale set with NIC  and what I am trying to do is to apply the backendpool config of basic Load Balancer to new standard Load Balancer. After implementing the advice from my team

I want to remove NIC from my virtual machine scale set but it display an error

Error image

```
Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration: Sequence contains no matching element
```

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoPkY.jpg)]

[image]

I am using this powershell script

```
Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -VirtualMachineScaleSet $myVmss -Name $myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

To resolve this make use of below powershell command like below:

Check whether in vmss two nic are assoicate like below:

```
$myvmss = Get-azvmss -ResourceGroupName <RGName> -vmscalesetName <VmssName>
$myvmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.Name
```

[image]

Update your virtual machine scale set using below command:

```
$myvmss | update-AzVmss
```

[image]

```bash
ResourceGroupName                      : v-imran
Sku                                    : 
  Name                                 : Standard_B1s
  Tier                                 : Standard
  Capacity                             : 2
ProvisioningState                      : Succeeded
UniqueId                               : XXXXXXX539f-4462-bd5f-513cdf4416a9
SinglePlacementGroup                   : False
PlatformFaultDomainCount               : 1
Identity                               : 
  Type                                 : UserAssigned
  UserAssignedIdentities               : 
{"/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-XXXXX/resourceGroups/AzSecPackAutoConfigRG/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/AzSecPackAutoConfigUA-eastus":{"principalId":null,"clientId":null}}
Id                                     : /subscriptions/b83c1ed3XXXXXX-2b83a0XXXXXXf/resourceGroups/v-imrankhan-mindtree/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/infra
Name                                   : 
Type                                   : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets
Location                               : eastus
Tags                                   : {"azsecpack":"nonprod","platformsettings.host_environment.service.platform_optedin_for_rootcerts":"true","Reason":"Repro","CreatedDate":
AM","CreatedBy":"NA","OwningTeam":"NA"}
```

***When I try to execute the same command it execute successfully like below:***

```
Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -VirtualMachineScaleSet $myVmss -Name $myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations me[1]
```

[image]

```
ResourceGroupName                      : v-imrankhan
Sku                                    : 
  Name                                 : Standard_B1s
  Tier                                 : Standard
  Capacity                             : 2
ProvisioningState                      : Succeeded
UniqueId                               : 552c5e81-539f-4462-bd5f-513cdf4416a9
SinglePlacementGroup                   : False
PlatformFaultDomainCount               : 1
Identity                               : 
  Type                                 : UserAssigned
  UserAssignedIdentities               : 
{"/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-XXXXX/resourceGroups/AzSecPackAutoConfigRG/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/AzSecPackAutoConfigUA-eastus":{"principalId":null,"clientId":null}}
Id                                     : /subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-XXXXXX/resourceGroups/v-imrankhan-mindtree/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/infra
Name                                   : infra
Type                                   : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets
Location                               : eastus
Tags                                   : {"azsecpack":"nonprod","platformsettings.host_environment.service.platform_optedin_for_rootcerts":"true","Reason":"Repro","CreatedDate":"
AM","CreatedBy":"NA","OwningTeam":"NA"}
VirtualMachineProfile                  : 
  OsProfile                            : 
    ComputerNamePrefix                 : infr
    AdminUsername                      : Imra    WindowsConfiguration               : 
      ProvisionVMAgent                 : True
```

Now, When I Check again NIC removed successfully like below:

[image]